# Selecting rows depending on conditions for multiple columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array and I want to select rows where I have some condition on different columns of those rows in Python using NumPy. For example consider this array:

```
test_array = numpy.array(([1,2,3,5],[4,5,6,7],[7,8,9,4]))
```

Now I want all rows where column 1 is `1` and column 4 is `5`.
So the output should be `[1,2,3,5]`, only 1 row in this case.

Comment: I removed the mysql tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following approach :

```
>>> test_array[np.where(np.all(test_array[:,[0,3]]==[1,5],axis=1))]
array([[1, 2, 3, 5]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[list(x) for x in test_array if x[0]==1 and x[3]==5]
```

This gives you the desired output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 5]]
```

For an array like this

```
test_array=numpy.array(([1,2,3,5],[4,5,6,7],[7,8,9,4],[1,98,76,5]))
```

you would then obtain

```
[[1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 98, 76, 5]]
```

Assuming you call the result `res`, you can the easily access the results. e.g. `res[1]` would then be `[1, 98, 76, 5]`.

If - for whatever reason - you would like to get the two numbers between the 1 and the 5 you could use

```
[sl[1:3] for sl in res]
```

which would give you

```
[[2, 3], [98, 76]]
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: No. I just have condition on few columns. Say I want all the rows where column1==a & column2==b and so on. I got the answer mentioned below

Comment: My code does exactly this (see first line of the answer; there you could also add more conditions), so I am not sure why you write "No" since the output is the desired one. But Kasra's version is probably much more efficient than mine once applied to huge arrays so I would have accepted his answer as well :) The rest of my answer was just thought as a bonus since I could imagine that you want to extract all the values which are not in the columns you base your selection on.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean indexing/masking does the job nicely

```
In [498]: test_array=np.array(([1,2,3,5],[4,5,6,7],[7,8,9,4]))

In [499]: I = (test_array[:,0]==1) & (test_array[:,3]==5)

In [500]: I
Out[500]: array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [501]: test_array[I,:]
Out[501]: array([[1, 2, 3, 5]])
```

When calculating `I`, use `()` freely so the `==` tests have priority over the `&`.  `Kasra`s test would also work: `I = np.all(test_array[:,[0,3]]==[1,5],axis=1)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function to be the criteria for rows, you can do:

```
def filter(row):
    if row[0]==1 and row[3]==5:
        return True
    return False

out_array = test_array[numpy.array([filter(row) for row in test_array])]
```

`numpy.array([filter(row) for row in test_array])` gives you a boolean array corresponding to which rows you want, and which you don't.

Answer (score -2):

test_array=np.array(([1,2,3,5],[4,5,6,7],[7,8,9,4]))
test_array[(test_array[:,0]==1) & (test_array[:,3]==5)]

Comment: You seem to be randomly copying code fragments from other existing answers. But you do not follow their lead of adding some explanation. Is there any additional insight you intend to contribute with your post?